# Get Controller settings properly in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-repositories

When I try to show Vacations for a specified User. I have

```
 URL: localhost:8080/api/user -> this getting me all users.

 localhost:8080/api/user/userId (like 22)/vacation -> this should be getting me all Vacations for this user.
```

I created VacationController where I have this method

```
@GetMapping("/api/user/{userId}/vacation")
public Vacation getVacations(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    return vacationService.findAllByUserId(userId);
}
```

In my service this method answer Repository which has:

```
@Repository
public interface VacationRepository extends JpaRepository<Vacation, Long> {
Vacation findAllByUserId(Long userId);
}
```

From my research on the internet, I have properly coded this, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by 'its not working'? Any error code, anything?

Try to change:

```
 Vacation findAllByUserId(Long userId);
```

to (findAll returns collection):

```
List<Vacation> findAllByUserId(Long userId);
```

Comment: please post the error in the text body of your question

Comment: @Deeadline post a project build file (pom.xml for maven, gradle.build for gradle) and User entity